# How to decide parameters of the property of an instance variable in iPhone os

Tags: iphone

I am noob in iPhone development..I have a query hope I you people will solve..

In every interface file(*.h file) we declare a property for every instance variable like this...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface Fruit : NSObject {


 NSString *name;
 NSString *description;
}

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *description;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString*)n description:(NSString *)desc;

@end
```

In this, how do we decide what will be parameters for the property of a variable????

thanks in advance..

Comment: Don't name your property `description`. There is already a method `-description` which you may not want to override.

Answer (score 2):

For string objects, you should use "copy" or "retain".
Typically, for most other objects you will use "retain".
For scalar types (int, float, etc), use "assign".

You can read about these Property Declaration Attributes [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW2).

Answer (score 0):

You set properties in an initialization method like so:

```
@implementation Fruit
@synthesize name;
@synthesize description;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString*)n description:(NSString *)desc{
    if (self=[super init]) {
        self.name=n;
        self.description=desc;
    }
    return self;
}
```